# Why is $\,X\!\cdot\!10\%\!\cdot\!10\%\,$ not the same as $\,X\!\cdot\!20\%\,$?

Tags: percentages

This confuses me a bit:

$X = 100$

Multiplying in two steps :

$100\cdot1.1 = 110$
$110\cdot1.1 = 121$

Directly multiplying by $1.2$ ($20\%$) :

$100\cdot1.2 = 120$

Comment: Because $.1\cdot .1\neq .1+.1$

Comment: Why should it be the same?  Also, this is $x\cdot 110\%\cdot 110\%$ as opposed to $X\cdot 120\%$

Comment: If you add $10$% to some positive value and then do this again, you add $10$% of a larger value at the second time.

Comment: The amount it increased by "in the second step" when "multiplying in two steps" was based on the **current** amount which is not the original amount.

Comment: Following the **first binomial formula** it is $(1+0.1)^2=1^2+2\cdot 1\cdot  0.1+0.1^2$=$1.2+0.01$ This should explain the extra $0.01$.

Comment: Black, multiplication tag is $\text{\$\cdot\$}$. For example : $\text{\$100 \cdot 1.1 = 110\$}$.

Comment: @QC_QAOA, actually, you should have written that the reason is that $\,(1+0.1)\!\cdot\!(1+0.1)\neq1+(0.1+0.1)\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x\cdot1.1\cdot1.1=x\cdot(1.1\cdot1.1)=x\cdot1.21\neq x\cdot 1.2$
multiplication is associative. 
alternatively, in words: multiply the first $1.1$ get $1.1x$, multiply the second $1.1$ it is adding $10\%$ of $1.1x$ towards $1.1x$ but not $10\%$ of $x$ towards the $1.1x$, hence different.